# How to create pre-trained model for LSTM with non-image data in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, pre-trained-model

I have **Data A** from accelerometer and gyroscope sensors like this

[image: Data from accelerometer and gyroscope sensors]

I want to create a pre-trained model to be used to classify with the LSTM method using **Data A** in python. Is that possible? Because from what I read, pre-trained is used for image data and uses methods such as CNN for classification. In addition, I tried to find data that has gone through the pre-trained process but have not found it so I doubt whether it is possible.

And if I do the classification using LSTM, can I use the A data that has gone through the pre-trained?
Is there a tutorial I can study? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to look at some HAR datasets you can find plenty of examples in Kaggle that are using a LSTM, the first one that comes to my mind is the excellent tutorial of Jason Brownlee https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the tutorial from Jason Brownlee is indeed my main source. Then what I want to do is create pre-trained data from **Data A** that comes from these sensors (accelerometer and gyroscope) and use it for classification using LSTM. Is it possible to do? Because the data is not an image.

Comment: Yes, the LSTM are created for signals in the language, later there were adapted to using in images, and don't forget that they are using a 2-dimension shape, so if  if you are data shape will be (n_timesteps,n_features) where time steps is how many samples you are taking and features will be two accelerator and gyroscope